# Balanced Parenthesis Order number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, puzzle

Suppose if you consider the case of length-six strings, the order would be: “()()()”, “()(())”, “(())()”, “(()())”, “((()))”.
In the above example, if we see that the strings in which the first opening parenthesis is closed the earliest come first, and if that is the same for two strings, the rule is recursively applied to the next opening parenthesis.

If particular balanced parenthesis sequence is given how to find the order number? Suppose ()(())--> Output is 2....In O(n) where n is the length of balanced parenthesis i.e 3 in above case...The input can be around 100000 balanced parenthesis

Comment: What did you try or what don't you understand? Do you see any solution that is slower than O(n)?

Comment: Is there anyway to identify the order number?...Suppose )((()) like this unbalanced parenthesis is given swapping them into proper balanced like this ()(()) with minimum number of swaps  & the order number after swapping...what is the order number without checking all other balanced parenthesis? Swapping part i got it @AndyT

Comment: What is "order number?" Do you mean the maximum nesting depth? Also, your comment above mentions fixing unbalanced parentheses, which is a completely different problem. *What problem are you trying to solve?*

Comment: Order number means Inverse Lexicographic order @jim mischel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the Ruskey thesis. This algorithm specified about the Ranking & unranking of binary trees.
http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/Thesis/ThesisPage16.png

Answer (score 1):

First let `g(n,k)` be the number of length `2n + k` strings there are with `n` pairs of balanced parentheses, which close `k` more parentheses.  Can we calculate `g(n,k)`?

Let's try recursion.  For that we first need a base case.  It is clear that if there are no balanced parentheses, then we can only have one possibility - only closing parentheses.  So `g(0,k) = 1`.  There is our base case.

Next the recursive case.  The first character is either an opening parenthesis, or a closing parenthesis.  If it is an opening parenthesis, then there are `g(n-1,k+1)` ways to finish.  If it is a closing parenthesis, then there are `g(n,k-1)` ways to finish.  But we can't have a negative number of open

1. `g(0,k) = 1`
2. `g(n,-1) = 0`
3. `g(n,k) = g(n-1, k+1)`

This lets us calculate `g` but is not efficient - we are effectively going to list every possible string in the recursive calls.  However there is a trick, memoize the results.  Meaning that every time you call `g(n, k)` see if you've ever called it before, and if you have just return that answer.  Otherwise you calculate the answer, cache it, and then return it.  (For more on this trick, and alternate strategies, look up *dynamic programming*.)

OK, so now we can generate counts of something related, but how can we use this to get your answer?

Well note the following.  Suppose that partway through your string you find an open parenthesis where there logically could be a close parenthesis instead.  Suppose that at that point there are `n` pairs of parentheses needed and `k` open parentheses.  Then there were `g(n, k-1)` possible strings that are the same as yours until then, then have a close parenthesis there (so they come before yours) and do whatever afterwards.  So summing `g(n, k-1)` over all of the close parentheses gives you the number of strings before yours.  Adding one to that gives you your position.